# extract lines from a flowdocument in a richtextbox starting with specific words WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I'm very new to wpf and I would like to make a text analysing tool.
I already know how to import text into rich textbox and format it properly, but now I want to run a method that extracts all lines in the flowdocument that start with INT or EXT and place them in a listbox. It seems to be quite easier to do this in winforms than in WPF.

Is there someone who can guide me with this?

I wish I could already provide some code but the flowdocument is new to me as is wpf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a code snippet to collect the lines that begin with INT or EXT.
I am sure the code is not optimal, because i am not practised with RichTextBox, but i think it is very easy to understand.

```
private List<string> CollectLines()
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
        TestRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
        // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
        TestRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

    // The Text property on a TextRange object returns a string 
    // representing the plain text content of the TextRange. 
    var text = textRange.Text;

    List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

    // Collect all line that begin with INT or EXT
    // Or use .Contains if the line could begin with a tab (\t), spacing or whatever
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(text))
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {

            if (line.StartsWith("INT") || line.StartsWith("EXT"))
            {
                resultList.Add(line);
            }

            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Maybe you can find out how you can put the list into a listbox yourself :)

Comment: This is indeed a great help. The listbox I know how to do. However the code gave me an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Illegal characters in path" Any idea how that happened or how to solve that? The text in the richtextbox contains only simple text.

Comment: Oh yes, i am Sorry - StreamReader is for files. when you put in the variable text it is no FilePath. That's the Reason for the Error. I will edit the code soon.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort. It's a great help for me

Comment: I changed the StreamReader into the StringReader. But StringReader has no EndOfStream Property. i hope checking the line != null will work